# How appropriate is this logistic regression analysis?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, multiple-comparisons

I am reviewing this study where they measured fathers' stress, anxiety and depression levels at four-time points. And they measured the child's behavioural problems only at the last time. They then created dichotomous variables from this data (whether there was or wasn't stress, depression, anxiety or behavioural issues). They created logistic models using the children's measure as the dependent variable and the father's measures as the independent. They created a model for each timepoint the father's distress measures were taken.
For each model, they then created another model adjusting for age, sex, father's age ...
Finally, they created a stepwise log regression with all fathers' and mothers' distress variables from all the time points to predict the children's behavioural problems.

I question whether you consider using a log regression appropriate with this data and whether they should have used one model with multilevel variables for stress, depression, and anxiety levels for each time point.

Also, in total, they did around ten models or so, given that they made different ones for each time point for each distress measure and then a combination of them. Should they correct for multiple comparisons, or do you think this might not be necessary in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So much wrong with what was done!

I do statistical reviews for a couple of journals and this would, for sure, be "major revision."

1. Dichotomizing variables is almost always a bad idea. It reduces power and increases type 1 error and doesn't let you ask some interesting questions.
2. What method should be used depends on the original scoring of the child's measure. This *might* be ordinal (none, mild, moderate, severe) or it might be a score from some scale that was factor analyzed, or it might be something else. If it's a yes/no variable then ... well, that's really not a good measure of "behavior problems".
3. A separate model for each time point is not a good way to go. I'm not sure what I would recommend. I would look at the patterns over time before deciding how to proceed (and I would look at these *without* relating them to the dependent variable. There are ways of doing cluster analysis on this sort of thing, that might make sense here. But some sort of accounting for this should be done.
4. Stepwise is a bad way to build a model. All the output is wrong. Standard errors are too small, p values too low, parameter estimates biased away from 0.
5. As for multiple comparisons and corrections, well Jacob Cohen said "this is a subject on which reasonable people may differ."   I don't often see corrections for multiple models of the sort you are describing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Peter, always so helpful.